# redux async with redux thunk doesn't work with @connect

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I try to use setTimeout as a mock for rest api, but my redux seems has flawed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1zr78rp48j

partial code

```
@connect(state => state.items, { approveItem })
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => approveItem()}>{this.props.loading ? 'loading...' : 'Approve'}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder why this simple flow won't work, is my setTimeout function in the reducer make sense? I'm using redux-thunk.

Comment: *”is my setTimeout function in the reducer make sense”* the reducer can *never* be async. Redux thunk allows your *actions* to be async. Have a look at the docs again.

Comment: @FelixKling so how will it look like without a real api library like fetch and axios?

Answer (score 2):

i have corrected your code , take a look

> https://codesandbox.io/s/14j6m2661q

the issue was in your class

```
export  class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(approveItem);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.items && this.props.items.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>Approve </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// start of code change
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { items: state.items };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

  return {
    approveItem: () => dispatch(approveItem())
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Items);
```

Comment: Pfff... And where is the decorator? Entire point of the question is why it doesn't work with @connect decorator.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with that but just use in the onclick listener  "this.props.approveItem()" instead of calling the  "approveItem()"

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam if I use decorator I don't see approveItem function in this.props

Comment: I can confirm that the only change i made in the sandbox code the OP provided was to call `this.props.approveItem()` and it works as expected.

Comment: @Sagivb.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807783/this-props-missing-method-using-conect-from-react-redux take a look on this strange issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want redux to take the action creators and wrap them in a function that will dispatch their result you have to [pass an object](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) with the action creators as it's members to mapDispatchToProps (you are doing this correctly).

But in the component you are not using the wrapped action creator, you are using the imported `approveItem` The correct code to create auto dispatched action creators is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { approveItem } from "./actions";
//mapDispatchToProps is an object here, all function members of the object
//  will be treated as action creators and wrapped in a function that when
//  called will automatically dispatch their result
const mapDispatchToProps = { approveItem };
@connect(state => state.items, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    //use the wrapped action creator found on this.props
    console.log(this.props.approveItem);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>Approve </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can manually wrap action creators in a function that will dispatch their results (actions). By passing a function to mapDispatchToProps.

This is is usually the case when you want to isolate components and not dump all reducers and actions on one pile. The application will wrap actions in `{type:"ITEM",action:actualItemComponentAction}`. Since the component doesn't know how to wrap it's actions in a action handled by application the application needs to pass wrappers to action creators that return functions for thunk and wrap actual action objects with a type that can be handled by the application reducer.

Not sure how [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) fits into this because if you manually want to bind action creators to components you usually don't want to auto bind them but rather want to wrap the component action in a application action.

An example work in progress can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkjwrm20r7).

Comment: any clue why I need `bindActionCreators` I used to not using any of them and my code will just work.

Comment: @JennyMok `approveItem` is only creating an action (because you have thunk the action is actually a function) but you don't dispatch it. Even if `approveItem` would create an action object I doubt it would be dispatched. Maybe you can provide an example of code that works? Action creators usually only create an action but don't dispatch it so calling an action creator function in a click handler wouldn't do anything unless you're dispatching the result of the action creator.

Comment: @JennyMok If you [don't import the action creator](https://codesandbox.io/s/r168qy634) and use `const approveItem = () => ({ type: "APPROVED" })` Then still nothing will happen when clicking the button. The function `approveItem` returns an object (action) but it's not dispatched and `connect` only puts `approveItem` on the props but does nothing in the way of dispatching it's result.

Comment: in this example https://github.com/eldyvoon/react-redux-express-auth/tree/master/src/App there's no need for `bindActionCreators`, but why it still work?

Comment: @JennyMok Updated answer, `mapDispatchToProps` takes an object with action creators and will put those on props wrapped in a function that will dispatch their result automatically. You did that part correctly but in the onClick function you're not using it, you should be using `this.props.approveItem`.

Comment: ok I got it, but I felt strange when I do console.log(this.props) in the render method I did not see approveItem function.