# this.props 'missing' method using conect from react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

https://codesandbox.io/s/6l8zr5k94k

Why when I do this.props I see only object but not the function? but this.props.approveItem is there, this is so strange.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { approveItem } from "./actions";

@connect(state => state.items, { approveItem })
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() { 
    console.log('where is approveItem?', this.props);
    console.log('approveItem is here', this.props.approveItem);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>Approve </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in codesandbox, this.props have that function check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/722rvzn086), let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: you don't need an inline arrow function, just call it directly: `<button onClick={this.props.approveItem}>Approve </button>`

Comment: @Sagivb.g I need, else the click is fired upon user entering the page, you can test it out urself

Comment: @JennyMok I had a typo, i fixed my comment. Take a look.

Comment: @JennyMok check my edited answer, i think i know why you are not seeing the function

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm not sure what exactly you are missing but</strike> running your code does print the `props` and shows the action as expected:

[image]

**Edit**
I think i know why you are not seeing the function when you log it.
You are looking at the `console` of the code sandbox application, which probably is doing a serialization of the `props` object.
The problem is that [functions are not serialize-able](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Example_of_using_JSON.stringify()_with_localStorage).

From the docs:

> Functions are not a valid JSON data type so they will not work.
>   However, they can be displayed if first converted to a string

You can run the code below to see how `JSON.stringify` for instance, is not serializing the function inside the object.

```js
const obj = {
  someKey: 'some Value',
  someFunc: function() {}
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

**FYI**: You don't need to create an inline arrow function to pass it down to the `onClick` event, you can just pass the reference via the `props`.

So change this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>Approve </button>
```

To this:

```
<button onClick={this.props.approveItem}>Approve </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`approveItem` function is available in `this.props`

```
this.props.approveItem()
```

`this.props` is always an object, never be a function, Just think if we need to have multiple functions in props, we can have multiple function only if `this.props` is object. Not possible if this.props is itself as function.

Seeing methods in this.props object. Please look into console - https://codesandbox.io/s/xpy0lmolr4

Comment: why approveItem is not within the object when I console.log(this.props)?

Comment: @JennyMok I'm, seeing all things under this.props, Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/xpy0lmolr4